# Matching data based on IDs

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, worksheet-function, excel-2011

I have two sheets, one is a huge table of item ID's with a corresponding code column next to them. However over time this has not been properly filled in. I have assembled a complete list of item ID's and corresponding codes in another sheet.

I want Excel to fill in the blanks using the ID column as a key.

What's the easiest way to get Excel to look for the ID in the main sheet, and paste in the corresponding code from the other sheet?

Comment: Exactly what i have done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than fill in just the blanks - and face the issue of how then to skip over cells already populated  - use the same formula to fill in the blanks and to overwrite whatever happens to be present already.